# Java | InputStreamReader(System.in) – it is not reading last line

Tags: java, while-loop, bufferedreader, inputstreamreader

been trying to solve *this* issue. Long story short, it does not read the ***last line*** of `my input`.

**What I want it to do... read the file and exit out.**

That's it. It works fine on a `file ( example: .txt )`, but when it comes to `System.in`, code does ***not*** work! Annoying, when it should be easy.

Here are the code and photos to recreate!

```
    StringBuilder strBuilder = new StringBuilder();
    String line;

    // for the last line to "end", I have to do \n! ... but how...?

    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));

    while((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
        System.out.println(line);
        strBuilder.append(line);
    }

    // Does not reach code
    System.out.println(strBuilder.toString());
```

I know `readLine()` terminates on a `\n` or `\r` ... in this case, `4 fourth line` does **NOT** have a line break after, so I tried using `!br.isEmpty()` or `!br.isBlank` to 'see' that there are no more lines after `4 fourth line` ... but I guess I am missing something.

`( copy and paste this info into the console without a line break after 4 fourth line )`

[image]

```
1 first line
2 second line
3 third line
4 fourth line
```

You will get this

[image]

You *WILL* get `4 fourth line` to print out if you press `ENTER` in the console ( because you are inputting a "\n" ) but that is not what I am expecting.

Currently, it will not terminate. It will not read the last line of user input. It will be in a loop.

Please help :)

Comment: Just press enter in your file after last line and check.

Comment: Your code will exit if you feed `CTRL` + 'Z` on a new line and press enter.

Comment: @code_mechanic, that does work, but the behavior I was looking for is that I don't have to do that, and let it end by itself. It may be a buggy assessment I did because it only took in user input without specifying an end of line character or an escape sequence, hence not reading the last line.

Answer (score 6):

`readline()` will read input up to newline character or up to end-of-file (whichever comes first).

If you do it properly, i.e. you pipe your file into the standard input of your java program, it should work. Like this: `cat myfile.txt | java MyClass` or `java MyClass < myfile.txt`. It will also work if you use a `FileInputStream` in place of `System.in`.

The problem is only when you are typing your input from console by hand. In this case `BufferedReader` has no way of knowing when your input is finished, so it waits until either a newline character or end-of-file. In Linux, you can simply press `Ctrl-D` to ask the console to close standard input to java program.

Comment: Hi @jurez, thank you for your reply. I currently tried to do an assessment recently for a company in HackerRank ... the platform just runs for test cases and you as the programmer can't really do much but just write the code. So `Ctrl-D` or any other ways are out of the question. Is there a workaround? Also, yeah didn't do so well with the assessment because of this issue.

Comment: So like, writing out to a file, doing anything with a file is also out of the question.

Comment: The question here is *how do I know where the input ends*? You can try to simply read all the input character-by-character until end-of-file, collect them into one big string and then split it into separate lines.

Comment: Inside the while loop, I made the readLine string into a `char[]` and printed them out to see their EOL number, the number `32` pops up for the EOL in each line. but when it reaches the last line (`4 fourth line`), it does not iterate though the last line at all, it seems like it is thinking the last line is`null`?... I am running out of ideas

Comment: @Flexer if hackerrank is sending you input and then not sending an end-of-stream line, then hackerrank is buggy and you should file a bug report. However, I rather doubt this. The code you pasted works fine in all situations except idiotic impossible ones, such as input that doesn't end in a newline and isn't closed - which is literally indistinguishable from a slow disk.

Comment: After exhausting all options, that is what it seems like. A buggy assessment. I understand what the answers you guys are giving me, I am very thankful :) I think I just needed to read that it is a possibility that it is a buggy assessment, which I previously thought it was. Since the assessment is from a company, I had to give it a benefit of the doubt. Moving forward headacheless, thank you again!! ( I may report to the company so that other candidates will not have to go through what I went through )

Answer (score 1):

In eclipse you paste your input, then click on other pane/window, then click on console and press `CTRL`+`Z` it takes it as null line and exits
On command prompt in windows you'll have to press the combination on new line and press enter.

Otherwise, you'll have to put condition like if the line is blank. You'll have to press enter to feed blank line to exit.

```
StringBuilder strBuilder = new StringBuilder();
        String line;

        // for the last line to "end", I have to do \n! ... but how...?

        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));

        while((line = br.readLine()) != null && !line.isBlank()) {
            System.out.println(line);
            strBuilder.append(line);
        }

        // Does not reach code
        System.out.println("Printing result:" + strBuilder.toString());
```

Output:

```
1 first line
2 second line
3 third line
4 fourth line1 first line
2 second line
3 third line

4 fourth line

Printing result:1 first line2 second line3 third line4 fourth line
```

Comment: Hi @onkar, I have explored this option in the beginning but not the behavior I was after. What I wanted to happen is that the code will read the till `4 fourth line` and exiting out of the loop. I may have had a buggy assessment because the input they were plugging in for test cases in HackerRank did ***not*** contain an escape sequence or a "\n" at the end of last line to terminate the code. Go figure! ‍♂️

Answer (score 0):

So to put this to rest, I believe it may have been a buggy assessment. The code below works as expected, and as all of you guys have said, that the code works fine. No more further investigation needed on this!

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

    StringBuilder strBuilder = new StringBuilder();
    BufferedReader readFile;

    try {
          readFile = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("/src/z_hackerRank_problems/z_IOfile.txt"));
          String contentLine;
          while ((contentLine = readFile.readLine()) != null) {
              strBuilder.append(contentLine).append(" ");
          }
    } catch (IOException ioException) {
        ioException.printStackTrace();
    }
    printHistogram(strBuilder.toString());

}
```

```
// z_IOfile.txt | notice '4 fourth line', no line breaks, no "\n" but code still iterates through
1 first line
2 second line
3 third line
4 fourth line
```

With FileReader, it works great. With InputStreamReader(System.in) ... not so much!

**TLDR;**

- code is supposed to read all through lines, but with `InputStreamReader(System.in)`, it does not recognize the end of line character/sequence if no **"\n**" | **"\r"** | **doing a command that stops the loop**.
- As said in this thread, the HackerRank assessment might need some revisions done as it may be a buggy one.